# Get HGLRC from QQuickView in qml 5.3

Tags: opengl, openglcontext, qquickview

How can I get HGLRC from QQuickView in qml 5.3 application?

I have a program on openGL in windows which I want render to my `QQuickView`. The problem is that I don't want to touch render process in openGL rendering process.
So, first I want create `QQuickView` and then get the HGLRC from it and set it to openGl prog by `wglMakeCurrent(...)` function.